Local JMX/jconsole doesn't work without -Djava.rmi.server.hostname
Emphasis: not using RMI here; just pure local jconsole/JMX
Problem: Local jconsole to JVM PID doesn't work unless I specify "java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname" (don't even need to give it a value but it must be defined). The PID is discoverable in the UI but SSL/insecure connections then fail
I am following tutorials like this one https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/jmx/java-management-extensions-jmx-technology-tutorial.html#GUID-215E9966-9BF6-4201-848A-FE860BDF3DAD
using local JMX (i.e. not using RMI).
All such local JMX tutorials state:

start JVM app (this opens no ports as expected since I am not using RMI) "java -jar myapp.jar"
run: jconsole
select application from the UI Local Process table

However when I do this it tries SSL / insecure then always fails.
If I use "java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname" then it works and jconsole connects by PID.
Question: for local JMX connections: has  "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname" become required even for local JMX (BTW: this breaks all the local jconsole tutorials)
Is there something about my system(multi-homed) that causes this?
System: JDK 17 on Fedora 40; has multiple NICs and IP addresses but the system hostname is resolvable
Update: solved - the system IP address had changed and the dynamic DNS did not update correctly. Face palm.

This is the attach mechanism failing.  Which version of Java are you using and how did you install it?  Have you tried with Oracle Java?

I am using the platform JDK which is Fedora's OpenJDK 17 - hmm - maybe that has different behaviour from Oracle's JDK. Tried also with Corretto JDK 21 with the same result. If I specify -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 both work.

Tried Oracle JDK 17 with the same issue.

You should write your findings up in a proper, well-explained answer for others to upvote.

Resolution: no args are necessary for jconsole/JVM on the same host; however, network DNS was misconfigured where the hostname did not
resolve to any of the host IP addresses. This resulted in failure of local JMX connections.
Background: with jconsole and JVM running on the same host you should not need to use any command line arguments for java ....  jconsole discovers all your local JVM processes through a combination of jps and filesystem /tmp/hsperfdata_<USERID>.
Connection: jconsole <JVM_PID> should just work.
In my case: the hostname did not resolve to a local IP address (misconfiguration of DNS in the network). As a result, jconsole <JVM_PID> would not connect.
Difference from jmxremote: with local JMX connections, apart from your application ports, the JVM doesn't open any additional ports. However, after the first connection, the JVM will open one additional random port and leave it open for future connections.
Here is an example of the jconsole app itself:
# before any local JMX connections
~> ss -apnt | grep 577147
~> # i.e. no ports open

# after the first JMX connection
~> ss -apnt | grep 577147
LISTEN     0      50                                       *:43721                        *:*     users:(("jconsole",pid=577147,fd=42))     

# a LISTEN port is left behind for future (local) JMX
# note: no jmxremote.port or jmxremote.rmi.port open

